# Outlook rest api "synchronize messages" ignores $expand in subsequent calls

Tags: rest, office365api, outlook-restapi, office365-restapi

I am trying to synchronize an Outlook folder (say the Inbox) using the beta version of the Outlook Rest Api [see doc here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#Synchronizemessagespreview)

I need only to retrieve the property *IsRead* and the *PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID*

So following documentation, for the first synchronization my requests look like:

The following Http headers are always added:

```
  request.Headers.Add("Prefer", "odata.track-changes");
  request.Headers.Add("Prefer", "odata.maxpagesize=5"); //Use a small page size easier for debugging
```

1. The first initial full synchronization request

   `https://outlook.office365.com/api/beta/Me/MailFolders('inbox')/messages?$select=IsRead&$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=(PropertyId eq 'String 0x1035'))`

   **Good results** the `value` array contain what I need.
2. The second request after the first request uses the *deltatoken*

   `https://outlook.office365.com/api/beta/Me/MailFolders('inbox')/messages?$select=IsRead,Subject&$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=(PropertyId eq 'String 0x1035'))&$deltatoken=a758b90491954a61ad463ef3a0e690a2`

   **Bad results**, no SingleValueExtendedProperties entries
3. Next requests for paginations with *skiptoken*...

   `https://outlook.office365.com/api/beta/Me/MailFolders('inbox')/messages?$select=IsRead,Subject&$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=(PropertyId eq 'String 0x1035'))&$skiptoken=e99ad10324464488b6b219ca5ed6be1c`

   **Bad results** again, same as 2.

It looks like a bug to me. Can you provide a workaround? From a list of *ItemId* is possible to retrieve easily the list of corresponding *PR_InternetMessage_Id* efficiently (not item per item)?

Note also that in the documentation it is written that:

> The response will include a Preference-Applied: odata.track-changes
>   header. If you attempt to sync a resource that is not supported, this
>   header will not be returned in the response. Check for this header
>   before processing the response to avoid errors.

It seems that for 2. and 3. calls this response header "Preference-Applied" is not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sync functionality today doesn't support extended properties. However, we are working to enable this and it should start working in a few weeks.

**EDIT:**
For a workaround for the very special case of the PR_INTERNETMESSAGE_ID look at the comment below.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. Is there a workaround that you could think about? For example, an 'efficient' request to get a list of `PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID` from a list of `ItemId`?

Comment: `InternetMessageId` is a first-class property in the beta namespace, could you just use that instead of using the extended property? Something like: `https://outlook.office365.com/api/beta/Me/MailFolders('inbox')/messages?$select=IsRead,InternetMessageId`

Comment: This workaround works perfectly, thank you very much. Could you report the missing "Preference-Applied" in the response header to dev team as well?